# @Before advice is not executing on overridden method in an abstract class in an external jar

Tags: aop, aspectj, spring-aop, aspect

I am trying to create a @Before advice on the method **`com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.update(Host, Statement, Exception, long)`**

**`com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger`** is an abstract class, it implements **`com.datastax.driver.core.LatencyTracker`** & overrides the method **`com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.update(Host, Statement, Exception, long)`**

I have kept the aop.xml file at the:
`src\main\resources\META-INF\aop.xml`

**aop.xml**

```
<aspectj>
    <weaver>
        <include within="com.datastax.driver.core.*"/>
        <include within="com.xxx.offline.aop.CassandraMetricsAspect"/>
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="com.xxx.offline.aop.CassandraMetricsAspect"/>
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

**Below is the Aspect class:**

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class CassandraMetricsAspect implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4731145870765590889L;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger();

    @Before("execution(* com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.update(..))")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        Object[] signatureArgs = joinPoint.getArgs();
        LOGGER.info("Classname " + joinPoint.getClass());
        for (Object signatureArg : signatureArgs) {
            LOGGER.info("Arg: " + signatureArg);
        }
    }
}
```

**I have included the following dependencies in my pom.xml**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11-RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId
            <version>1.8.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.11</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Last, I am using the javagent as follow in the eclipse run config:**

`-javaagent:"I:\cig-maven-repo\org\springframework\spring-instrument\4.3.12.RELEASE\spring-instrument-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar"`

I do not see the aspect class getting executed. I have used the following point-cut expression, none of them worked

1. **`execution(* *.*(..))`**, I did not see the QueryLogger class's update method being intercepted.
2. **`execution(* com.datastax.driver.core.LatencyTracker+.update(..))`**
3. **`execution(* com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.update(..))`**

Any help will be appreciated.

**Update 1:** 
Below is the verbose log from AspectJ

```
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.8.11 built on Tuesday Sep 26, 2017 at 15:08:44 GMT
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info register classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info using configuration /I:/md/md-batch/md-reactor/md/target/classes/META-INF/aop.xml
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] info register aspect com.xxx.offline.aop.CassandraMetricsAspect
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] weaveinfo Join point 'method-execution(void com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger$ConstantThresholdQueryLogger$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7a2e78f3.update(com.datastax.driver.core.Host, com.datastax.driver.core.Statement, java.lang.Exception, long))' in Type 'com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger$ConstantThresholdQueryLogger$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7a2e78f3' (<generated>) advised by before advice from 'com.xxx.offline.aop.CassandraMetricsAspect' (CassandraMetricsAspect.java)
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] warning javax.* types are not being woven because the weaver option '-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true' has not been specified
```

If we notice, the method name weaved is as below:

`method-execution(void com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger$ConstantThresholdQueryLogger$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$124ff4f8.update(...... omitted for brevity)`

In my Aspect class, I have specified **`com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.update(..)`**.

Is the difference between both method signatures the reason for discrepancy?

**Update 2:**

```
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MDJobConfiguration {
 Bean definitions... 
}

@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = {"com.xxx.offline.repository"})
public class CassandraConfiguration {
    Bean definitions... 
}

@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("env.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.xxx.offline")
public class MerchantDirectoryBusinessDelegate implements CommandLineRunner{
    Spring Boot execution class
}
```

[image]

I do see that I have Spring AOP dependencies coming from Spring Batch, web & context modules. Attaching the image

Comment: If the pointcut `execution(* *.*(..))` does not work, it means that the pointcut is not the main problem but the setup is. Maybe your "include within" is too narrow. Perhaps your target classes are not directly in package `com.datastax.driver.core` but in sub-packages. In that case you should write `com.datastax.driver.core..*` (two dots!). You could also use `<weaver options="-verbose">` and check the log output. Does anything get woven? Give it a spin and tell me if it helps.

Comment: Thank for the advise. I am seeing that QueryLogger class gets woven. Adding the log as **Update 1**.

May this relates to Spring vs CGLIB proxy classes?

Comment: How is Spring configured with regard to AspectJ vs. Spring AOP? Please update again and also show your XML or annotation-based Spring configuration. What is clear so far is that AspectJ load-time weaving works, but I also see a CGLIB proxy here, created by Spring (AspectJ does not use CGLIB). Maybe you even have Spring AOP and AspectJ both active at the same time, I cannot say without further information. But the aspect should log your method parameters if the target method is called. A bit strange to log another logger class, though... ;-)

Comment: @kriegaex - Added details as Update 2. Excluding Spring AOP causes Spring Boot to fail during start. Also, I would like to highlight that QueryLogger class is in the Cassandra driver jar, which is a different jar from the application

**com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger** is an abstract class, it implements **com.datastax.driver.core.LatencyTracker** & overrides the method **com.datastax.driver.core.QueryLogger.update(Host, Statement, Exception, long)**

Comment: I did not mean to exclude the JAR, I was only talking about Spring config. I am not a Spring user, but from what I know it looks okay. AspectJ weaver also works, so if the aspect still does not log anything it means that the woven pointcut is never executed in your application even though you think it should be. What happens if you change the pointcut to `execution(* *(..))`? And where is your aspect's logger logging to? Maybe just replace the logger output by `System.out.println(..)` for debugging. P.S.: An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be better than just snippets.

Comment: Thank for your interest in this problem. When I put a breakpoint in the `update` method of the `QuerryLogger` class, I do see that the `update` method gets executed. 

I do not see `QueryLogger` class being printed when change the pointcut to `execution(* *.*(..))` 

Is the expression `execution(* *.*(..))` different from `execution(* *(..))`?

Comment: No, my pointcut is just a shorthand for yours. Now I have run out of ideas, where is the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? No need to upload company secrets, just make a copy of your project and extract a minimal example reproducing the problem from it. Please also include a Maven build. Then push it to GitHub. The problem must be in the part of your project you are hiding from me.

Comment: I am working on MCVE. Will share you by tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: BTW, you have not answered my question. Did you try to replace the logger output by `System.out.println(..)` with the catch-all pointcut activated?

Comment: Yes, I had all the pointcuts printed on console, but QueryLogger didn’t appear in it...

Comment: So you did get log output? That means, AspectJ is working just fine, but your pointcut does not match what is executed, as I already said. Will probably be easy to spot as soon as I see the MCVE tomorrow. Talk to you then.

Comment: Hello @kriegaex,

I have MCVE to the following link https://github.com/ankursrivastava16/batch-reactor. In this setup i do not see the Querlogger class being weaved.

Comment: So the MCVE behaves different from your original application? I thought it reproduces your problem. A misunderstanding maybe? BTW, I cannot start the application: _"APPLICATION FAILED TO START (...) Field departmentService in (...).MainRunner required a bean of type '(...).DepartmentService' that could not be found."_

Comment: Please use the following github repo. https://github.com/abnig/cassandra-query-metrics

I have resolved all errors. Now, I can see that weaving is happening correctly but the Aspect class is not getting executed. Thanks